# Losing click even when page is loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

I have a page with a left nav which has two links and a main div. The main div is updated with content from the server whenever user clicks a link in the left nav. I use pjax for this.

When user initially comes to this page, the main div has a link with id `somelink` that shows an alert box when the user clicks the hyperlink. This is accomplished by this code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() { 
    .....
    $('#somelink').click(function (event){
       alert("here");
    });
     ....
   });
```

When the second link on the nav bar is clicked, I load content from the server and update the main div. When user clicks first link, again I load content from the server and update the main div. However, this time when I click `somelink` nothing happens. Its as if jQuery isn't able to detect that there is a link with id `somelink` because it was loaded via ajax.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: I assume this is in $(document).ready(...

Comment: yes, its in document ready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.on` and delegate the click handler to a higher level element that isn't being replaced since it's loaded with AJAX.

```
$(main).on('click', '#somelink', function() {
    alert("here");
});
```

The reason being that when you do `$('#somelink')`, it goes through the DOM and finds each one as it is. So, when you remove it by replacing, you either need to add that again or use `.on`

Comment: "main" is the containing DOM element that does not get replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You've replaced the elements and so the attached events. You need to add them differently to make them automatically available after dom updates.

Try the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$('#somelink').on('click', function() {});
```

Older jQuery versions do the with the "live" function and with even more older version you have to bind your events again after every dom update.